# Library: onElementReady to detect multiple elements existing at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, mutation-observers

I saw this code: https://gist.github.com/sidneys/ee7a6b80315148ad1fb6847e72a22313

This is pretty nice, a way to detect changes inside a page.

Is there any way to make it detect defined elements and when all exist, execute a command?

Because no matter how many elements I define, it will trigger the function when one of them exists.

But I need to wait for all elements to appear, otherwise is it too early.

I want to achieve something like

```
onElementReady('element1 && element2 && element3', true, (el) => {
  console.log('All element1, element2, element3 exist!')
})
```

How can I make it trigger the function when multiple elements exist?!

Comment: Have you tried using a singular selector for all elements, then checking `was-queried` in callback?

Comment: @AasthaBist That's the issue, I need more elements to match, then to trigger a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since onElementReady returns a Promise we can use Promise.all:

```js
(async () => {
  const elems = await Promise.all([
    'elem1',
    'elem2',
    'elem3',
  ].map(e => onElementReady(e, true)));
  console.log(elems);
})();
```

Comment: So I can use this together with the code in the gist? Don't I need to change the original code at all?  I'm not sure how to use your code, where I put my own function?

Comment: This code replaces your code in the question so you can use it in the same fashion.

Comment: Btw, is it also possible the following scenario:

wait for elem1 && elem2 && (elem3 || elem4)

then trigger a function?! If yes, can you tell me how can I achieve this as well? 

Comment: Use this code with `'elem3, elem4'` as instead of `'elem3'`.

Comment: Uhm, there's a problem. Your code doesn't run anymore between different pages. I want to use this on websites that depend on AJAX.  I mean I created a function that includes your async thing, but it won't do anything even though I call the function after the new page is loaded. :(

Comment: Try changing the second parameter from true to false. If it doesn't help, create a new question with your new code.

Comment: But if I set it to false, it will keep searching for the elements. I set it to true, then it waits for the elements and it stops. When a new page is loaded via AJAX, I want to be able to call again onElementReady. :/

Comment: Can you help me in this new question?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348012/onelementready-detecting-simultaneous-elements